# Not equal statement, not working

Tags: python

I am making a small quiz that has different difficulties, when doing my easy section my if statement always prints incorrect even with the correct answer - i am still new to python it might be a very easy thing to solve 
How can I know if this is a duplicate if i don't know what is wrong
here is my code

```
def easy():
    score = 0
    print("Welcome to the easy section!")
    print("****************************")
    print("Random Access Memory(1)")
    print("Radical Amazonian Mandem(2)")

    qe1 = input("What does RAM stand for?:    ")

    if qe1 == 1:
        score = score + 1
        print("Well done, next question:")

    if qe1 != 1:
          print("Incorrect, next question:")

    else:



easy()
```

Comment: You have to cast your input as an int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`input` function return a `string`, you should cast it to `int`:

```
    qe1 = int(input("What does RAM stand for?:    "))
```